# How to plot a graph of a function

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a 3d graph for the function
$$u(x,y,t)=\exp(x+y-3t),\quad   0\leq x,\,y\geq 1,\,t\geq0$$
Please some help me to get over this.

Comment: 3D plots of functions can be obtained with, well, `Plot3D`. However, your function has three arguments, so three dimensions won't suffice for plotting it...

Answer (score 2):

You can't really plot a 4D plot. But you could fix time and plot it for each instance of time. Like this

[image]

```
Manipulate[
   Grid[{ {Row[{"u at time ",t}]},
          {Plot3D[u[x,y,t],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},
                  ImageSize->300,
                  ImageMargins->5,
                  PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1},{0,8}},
                  AxesLabel->{"x","y","u(x,y,t)"},
                  BaseStyle->14]
          }
        }],

   {{t,0,"time"},0,1,.01,Appearance->"Labeled",ContinuousAction->True},
   TrackedSymbols:>{t},

Initialization:>
  (
    u[x_,y_,t_]:=Exp[x+y-3t]
  )
]
```

Comment: "You can't really plot a 4D plot." Well, there is `ContourPlot3D`, which does a 4D plot in some sense.